# Import PostgreSQL into MS Access OBDC Error While Exectuing the Query #7

Tags: postgis, ms-access

Trying to import a table from PostgreSQL to MS Access (2007) however, I keep getting the error

> OBDC Call Failed - Error While Executing the Query #7

STEPS TAKEN

1. In OBDC Data Source Admin (32-bit), under System DSN I added a new data source, the data source was my PostgreSQl localhost server.
2. In MS Access I added OBDC Database and selected 'Import the source data into new table in current database'
3. In Select Data Source panel that appeared I selected the DSN I created earlier. It showed the list of tables on PostgreSQL. When I selected on the table I was after, it showed the error mentioned earlier.

The basic idea is trying to link spatial attribute table stored on PostgreSQL to MS Access. Would like to know if possible and if so, how to go about it? If not possible due to MS Access limitations then other recommendations?

Note: The database table that I'm trying to import into Access was from the attribute table for a shapefile created on QGIS which is now stored on PostgreSQL. The table has no geometry associated with it (I exported the attributes as an csv - this was the csv I uploaded to PostgreSQL)

Comment: It's not clear as to why this is a GIS question (Access does not support Simple Features for SQL).  Please [Edit]  the question to explain what you are attempting and what data might be in Query #7

Comment: Hi Vince, thanks for your response. I've updated the question. So you're saying its not possible?

Comment: Was only the "attribute table" converted, or was geometry loaded as well? We can't predict what is possible without a a thorough description of what is being attempted. Esri used Access for Personal Geodatabase format, but geometry management was all custom code.

Comment: @BERA mentioned in post

Comment: @Vince also mentioned in updated post

Comment: There is no GIS component to your question. Ask it on stackoverflow